# C. Malloc И String

Tags: c, строки, char, malloc

Я как-то криво скопировал предыдущий код:
использовал **Malloc**, чтобы создать массив строк, но он создался как `Int` (в коде видно).
В общем, он работает, поэтому я его и не заметил (+ не слишком опытен).

**Задача:**

Я хочу удалить последний символ (или принт сделать так, чтобы последний элемент игнорить **ИЛИ** как-то по-хитрому присвоить такую же строку без последнего элемента)  `M[i]`-го элемента (все `М[i]`-строки).
А так как я создал всё криво, я без понятия, как с этим работать.

**Не могли бы вы подсказать, что делать без полного переделывания ?**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    //для сохранения input
    char res[400]="";
    
    
    FILE* input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE* output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    
    // само считывание 
    if (input != NULL) {
        fgets(res, 400, input);
        fclose(input);
    }
    //массив для "СЛОВ"
    //////---------------------------------------------------
    int size_M = 500;
    int* M = (int*)malloc(size_M * sizeof(int));
    //для размера/ количества элементов
    int index_M = 0;
    //////---------------------------------------------------

    // Заполняю М с помощью strtok
    char sep[] = " ";

    char* small = strtok(res,sep);

    while (small != NULL)
    {
        M[index_M] = small;
        index_M++;

        small = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }

    


    for (int i = 0; i < index_M; i++) {
        printf("%s-",M[i]);
    }

    fclose(output);
    
}
```

Comment: Я хочу удалить последний символ - последний символ ЧЕГО Вы хотите удалить? Файла, строки, каждого слова?

Comment: @S.H., Там написано, удалить последний символ М[ i ] (где все М[ i ] - это вроде бы строки). М - массив строк ( должен быть ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Постановка задачи:

"Я хочу удалить последний символ M[i]-го элемента"

у Вас присваивание `M[index_M] = small;` происходит толко в одном месте. Причём, больше ни для чего, кроме как для печати на экране, M[] не используется.

Логично именно здесь сразу присваивать "элемент без последнего символа".

Как бы это сделать? я бы написал так

```
    // "на коленке" считаем длинну строки
    int small_len=0;
    while(!small[small_len++]);
    small_len--;

    // если длинна больше 1 - то откусываем последний символ и делаем присваивание
    if (small_len>1){
        small[small_len-1]=0;
        M[index_M] = small;
        index_M++;    
    }
```

Попробуйте прогнать на каком то примере, может, я и не сильно ошибся :-)

Comment: спасибо большое, как будет минутка свободная, проверю)